# Triple inheritance, no unique final overrider

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a templated base class called Request :

```
template <typename Input, typename Output>
class Request
{
   public:
      // Constructor
      Request(const std::string& request) : request_(request) {}

      // Operation
      virtual Output select(const Input& arg) = 0;

      protected:
         // Attribute 
         const std::string request_;   
};
```

I also created a class that resolves the template specifically to search for, and this is only an example, phone numbers from, say, usenames.

```
// Special request that get phone numbers from usernames
class PhoneRequest : public virtual Request<std::string, std::string>
{
   public:
   protected:
      std::string username_;
};
```

Then I created two classes that search into two SQL tables :

```
class NationalPhoneRequest : public virtual PhoneRequest
{
    public:
       // Real request that actually get data from the database
       virtual std::string select(const std::string& username)
       {
           username_ = username;
           return call_sql_national(request_, username_);
       }
};

class InterNationalPhoneRequest : public virtual PhoneRequest
{
    public:
        // Real request that actually get data from the database
        virtual std::string select(const std::string& username)
        {
            username_ = username;
            return call_sql_international(request_, username_);
        }
};
```

Then, as I wanted to test my code, I created a generic Fake class :

```
template <typename Input, typename Output>
class Fake : public virtual Request<Input, Output>
{
    public:
        // Constructor
        Fake(const std::string& request) : Request<Input, Output>(request) {}  
        // Fake Operation
        virtual Output select(const Input& arg)
        {
            return data_[arg];
        }

        // Add fake data
        void add_data(const Input& key, const Output& data)
        {
            data_[key] = data;
        }

    private:
        // Contains fake data
        std::map<Input, Output> data_;
};
```

And finally, I created a class that would be able to simulate both InterNationalPhoneRequest and NationalPhoneRequest as these two are very close together. That class would also be a Fake. I am using the keyword "using" to explicitly indicates that this class must use the Fake base class method.

```
class FakePhoneRequest : public NationalPhoneRequest, public InterNationalPhoneRequest, public Fake<std::string, std::string>
{
    public:
        using Fake<std::string, std::string>::select;
};
```

I also created another class that uses everything before :

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo(NationalPhoneRequest* nat, InterNationalPhoneRequest* internat)
        : nat_(nat)
        , internat_(internat)
        {
        }


        std::string getNatPhoneNumber(const std::string& user)
        {
            return nat_->select(user);
        }

        std::string getInterPhoneNumber(const std::string& user)
        {
            return internat_->select(user);
        }

    private:
        NationalPhoneRequest* nat_;
        InterNationalPhoneRequest* internat_;
};
```

However, g++ fails complaining that :

> no unique final overrider for ‘Output Request::select(const Input&) [with Input = std::basic_string;
>   Output = std::basic_string]’ in ‘FakePhoneRequest’  class
>   FakePhoneRequest : public NationalPhoneRequest, public
>   InterNationalPhoneRequest, public Fake

I have a few questions.
1) Why does it fail ?
2) There is a trigger in my mind telling me that I am doing something wrong, probably the use of a triple inheritance.

I am doing it right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your child class is in fact inheriting three completely separate "select" functions that still exist in the child, "using" just lets you use "select" as a shorthand name for one of them. The three existing select functions aren't "combined" by doing this.

Basically, inheriting three virtual functions with the same name would give the child three different virtual function pointers, one for each "type" of select (since they're in different heirarchies).

C++ doesn't allow this because there would be no way to properly define the child-versions of all three select functions separately, since they'd all have to be called "select" which would confuse the hell out of your compiler.

If the three select functions took different parameters then there might not be a problem. The "internal" name of a function is defined both by the given name, and some tokens that define what parameters it takes. So "select" that takes one string is a different "named" function to select that takes two strings. As long as the compiler can work out which function is which then it's no problem to re-used names.

Having said that, the code kinda has a stink about it. Any time you're getting too deep wit inheritance-related things there are almost always better ways to do things. A rule of thumb is to try and keep inheritance only 1 level deep and have the base class being abstract (i.e cannot be instantiated by itself). Then you use pointers to the base class to "plug in" functionality into different classes (which themselves might be children classes of 1-deep abstract classes).

e.g. make a "PhoneDialler" class which has a pointer to a PhoneRequest. Then you have a function that returns a pointer to one of the PhoneRequest types. This is called a factory method. The PhoneDialler then just asks for a PhoneRequest object and uses it, and doesn't need to know about the child classes of PhoneRequest at all. This makes the system much easier to expand with new types.

Comment: Thanks a lot, however, I am worried that it would allow one to put a InternationalPhoneRequest into a variable that should contain a national one. What if I want to add special operations in InterNationalPhoneRequest ?

Comment: And your factory function handles giving out pointers to your request objects, so it contains the rules about which type is appropriate.

Comment: I don't get it. I need NationalPhoneRequest and  InterNationalPhoneRequest to derivate from PhoneRequest which itself derivates from Request. And my FakePhoneRequest must be at least a PhoneRequest (so that Foo can use it) and a Fake (so that I can add my special data). For a more rigorous typing, I chose that  FakePhoneRequest had to inherit from InternationalPhoneRequest and NationalPhoneRequest as I wanted to be impossible to put a InternationalPhoneRequest into the var designed to contain a NationalPhoneRequest. How should I design this with a Factory pattern ?

Comment: Try deriving a separate FakeNationalPhoneRequest and FakeInternationalPhoneRequest. Make them inherit from their respective classes and "Fake", but *stop* Fake from also inheriting from Request.  Have the derived classes handle the "fakeness".
With a factory pattern, you make a class or function where other objects request items, and the factory ensures that they get back objects that are appropriate. So the factory handles the "rules" in a centralized manner, rather than having the "rules" encoded into the actual data structures.

Comment: As for the pattern I was talking about before,it's more of the Strategy Pattern.Another way you could do it is to use templates instead of inheritance. make a Request<T> template,and you can fill that with a <National> or <International> object.Templates would still give you compile-time checking that National and International never get mixed up. Inside National and International,put a pointer to a "Handler" object. Have the base class for that as the "normal" handler and a derived "Fake" one.Then each Request object is the same externally, but they're all loaded with their own handler code